# Add Forms authentication to Durandal Template project

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I want to use the Durandal SPA Template in Visual Studio 2012.  Unfortunately it doesn't have Forms Authentication controllers and views etc in the template.  I can add all this manually but wanted to see if anyone knew if there was a quick way via nuget or anything that will add these on for me?

Essentially I want to create a login screen before the SPA. Using an existing database which used Forms authentication before so need to keep the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just install the Durandal Starter Kit from nuget on top of an existing project that includes the forms authentication bits that you need.